# Compare angular grid column cell texts against a string array using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, angular-promise

I am new to typescript and looking to scrape a list of values from an ag-grid column and compare it against a string array. Here is the function I wrote to achieve that. But my ActualRatingsValues.push(text); does not seem to be populating the array ActualRatingsValues. I don't really understand how promises work. Is this to do with promises ?

```
validateRatingsValues() {
   const ExpectedRatingsValues: Array<string> = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
   const ActualRatingsValues: Array<string> = [];
   const wrapper = element.all(by.css('.ag-pinned-left-cols-container div[col-id="name"]'))
            .getText()
            .then(text => {
                ActualRatingsValues.push(text);
            });

    let match = true;
    if (ExpectedRatingsValues != null && ActualRatingsValues != null) {
        if (ExpectedRatingsValues.length !== ActualRatingsValues.length) {
            match = false;

        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < ActualRatingsValues.length; i++) {
                if (ActualRatingsValues[i].toString !== 
                    ExpectedRatingsValues[i].toString) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        match = false;
    }

    expect(match).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Comment: FYI it's good practice that your test are between 10-12 lines of code

Comment: most of it is the compare code that I can move out to another function. but I am stuck trying to get the values from the page into an array. Any advise ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1)  `ActualRatingsValues.push(text)` should be `ActualRatingsValues.concat(text)`

because `element.all().getText()` return a promise which eventual value is an **string array**, not a **string**.

2) `wrapper` is a promise, you assign value to `ActualRatingsValues` within a promise.
In order to consume `ActualRatingsValues`, you have to consume it inside promise `then()`

```
validateRatingsValues() {
    const ExpectedRatingsValues: Array<string> = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
    const wrapper = element.all(by.css('.ag-pinned-left-cols-container div[col-id="name"]'))
            .getText();

    let match = wrapper.then(function(ActualRatingsValues) {
        let length = ExpectedRatingsValues.length;

        for(let i=0;i<length;i++) {
            let find = ActualRatingsValues.includes(ExpectedRatingsValues[i]);
            if (find === false) {
                return find;
            }           
        }

        return true;     
    });

    // match is also a promise which eventual value is a boolean
    // why below expect doesn't consume match inside then()
    // because Jasmine can detect match is a promise and do the assertion
    // inside then() in its implement internally.
    expect(match).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised you aren't getting an error trying to push to `ActualRatingsValues` since it is a `const`.

What's happening here is the lines following your `getText()` call are actually being executed before all the promises are returned. That's why it seems like it isn't working. The easiest option would be to implement async/await.

Here is what that would look like: (note that I also cleaned up the code a bit)

```
async validateRatingsValues() {
    const ExpectedRatingsValues: Array<string> = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

    // this will wait for all the promises to be returned before proceeding
    const wrapper = await element.all(by.css('.ag-pinned-left-cols-container div[col-id="name"]'))
              .getText()

    wrapper.forEach(item => {
        expect(ExpectedRatingsValues.indexOf(item)).toBeGreaterThan(-1);

        // this should work too
        expect(ExpectedRatingsValues).toContain(item);
    }

    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(ExpectedRatingsValues.length);
}
```

There are definitely ways to get this working without implementing async/await. I tried briefly to create an example and then realized my example wasn't going to work. I suggest reading the question/answer that Matt posted in the comments for a better understanding. There is a lot of good info in there.